# Building a Rohloff wheel

Tags: wheels, wheel-building

I want to equip my my Surly Ogre with a Rohloff hub.  I plan to do a lot of touring but also want to ride locally on both pavement and single-track, figuring on changing the tires when going on extended tours.

**- How do I determine which version of Rohloff Speedhub I need?**

**- In building a new wheel, what are the pros-cons of choosing a through-axle vs a quick-release?**

**- For this type of riding, what type rim would be best?  Touring?  ATB?  MTB?  What characteristics should I be looking for?**

**- Is there a type of tire that would serve best for both pavement and off-road?**

---

More specifically, I am trying to answer the following:

**1. Which hub.** From what I can tell so far, the "Rohloff Speedhub 500/14 TS DB OEM2" is the I want. I would prefer a quick release, but (and please correct me if I'm wrong) I understand it would difficult to remove the wheel, hence the "TS" version.

**2.  Rims.**  I am thinking of using the Velocity Blunt SS rims which have an effective rim diameter of 597 because they will allow tire widths of 45mm to 65mm (I could use 45mm for touring and 65mm at home for everything from pavement to rocky single-track).  Is this a good choice?  Any other recommendations?

**3.  Spoke length.**  According to Velocity's website, the Blunt SS has an effective rim diameter (ERD) of 597.  But Rohloff's table does not provide a spoke length for that ERD on a 29" wheel with 36 holes.  https://www.rohloff.de/de/service/handbuch/speedhub/tabellen#c25699
I also thought of using Sapim Race Spokes and tried their spoke calculator (https://www.sapim.be/spoke-calculator) but can't find some of the measurements required.

**4.  Tires.**  I like the Schwalbe Marathons for touring (other recommendations?).  But no idea what to use for my everyday, local, leaning on the side of (not-too-vigorous) single-track.

**5.  Or...  I could just buy it online.**  Of course, I may be better off to just order a custom Rohloff wheel online.  Any recommendations on providers?

Comment: There's a bunch of separate questions here, which leads to long meandering answers.   Try and cut it down.    Worry about tyres later.  Since the hub is expensive, the additional cost of getting a wheel hand built for you may be acceptable and will last longer than something built by a first time wheel builder.

Comment: Quick release (CC) vs TS: Rohloff specifications say that you have to use TS with horizontal dropout. (My *guess* would be that QR may not allow suffcient force to prevent the axle sliding forward) I don't see much of a difference in the hassle of removing the wheel? But then I'm biased: I decided I want to have a hub of that price  very much not-too-quick to release, so I got the CC version with pitlock (which was back then available only for QR). (my frame has a horizontal slider plate for adjusting for chain length with a vertical dropout for the axle, though)

Comment: **spokes**: ERD 597mm is in the Rohloff table under 28", listing 262 mm spoke length for 36 holes and 2 crossings. **buying**: At least over here in Germany, Rohloff cooperates with ses-sandmann.de offers to ship the hub to the wheel builder who will then build you a wheel according to your specs.  **tires** I have Schwalbe Marathon Mondial for most of the year (except I change to spike tires for winter) (They last me about 15000 km, changing front <-> back according to wear)